# calling checkBox1_CheckedChanged function in c++

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

can somebody tell me how to call

```
checkBox1_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
```

function?
i tried:

```
checkBox1_CheckedChanged(checkBox1,EventArgs::Empty);
```

and

```
checkBox1_CheckedChanged(checkBox1,gcnew EventArgs());
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you hooked up this event handler with an actual event? Not an expert on CLR but it seems to me you are trying to manually call this, athough it should be called during an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your call from:

```
checkBox1_CheckedChanged(checkBox1,EventArgs::Empty);
```

to:

```
CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(checkBox1,EventArgs::Empty);
```

(notice the first letter C is capitalized).

Comment: error C3861: 'CheckBox1_CheckedChanged': identifier not found

Comment: @user1100671 Well, it looks like your function name does not have the capital 'C' like your original post showed (since edited).  Your code works for me.  Perhaps the way you're determining that 'nothing has happened' is incorrect?

Comment: nope, because i used MessageBox::Show() function inside of CheckBox1_CheckedChanged()

Comment: @user1100671 hmm, a mystery.  When you right-click the function call in VS and select 'Go To Definition' does it jump to the function you exepect it to?